# Modifying two attributes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to modify two attributes of a node based on the value of one of them. If @dc="R" and @rt="UM" then I need to change @dc to "NF" and remove the @rt attribute. Here is how I tried to go about it but this is deleting all sub-elements of the document.

Sample document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ID dc="R" rt="UM" other="attr">
    <foo>bar</foo>
</ID>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@dc = 'R' and @rt = 'UM']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="nf"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@dc" mode="nf">
    <xsl:attribute name="dc">
        <xsl:text>NF</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@rt" mode="nf"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="nf">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ID dc="NF" other="attr"/>
```

The `<foo>` tag and its text are gone. Is there a better way to go about this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your 2nd template has `node` instead of `node()`. And you should probably add the mode to the `xsl:apply-templates` in the last template, too. Although I don't think you need to use mode at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If @dc="R" and @rt="UM" then I need to change @dc to "NF" and remove
>   the @rt attribute.

Could you not do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@dc[.='R' and ../@rt='UM']">
    <xsl:attribute name="dc">NF</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@rt[.='UM' and ../@dc='R']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@dc='R' and @rt='UM']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="dc">NF</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='dc' or name()='rt')] | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Will this work? Won't one of the templates change the attribute, causing the other not to match?

Comment: @Derek One template matches the `dc` attribute and changes it. Another template matches the `rt` attribute and suppresses it. There is no conflict here. Note that both templates have a *predicate* in their match patterns, to ensure they only operate when the two conditions are met. Otherwise the *identity transform* template will take over, copying everything as is.

Comment: In your first example, let's say the first template hits, it will change `@dc` to NF, won't that then cause the predicate `@dc='R'` to miss?

Comment: No, because the templates operate on the input, not on the result tree.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this XSLT does help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">                               <!-- identity template -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ID[@dc = 'R' and @rt = 'UM']">            <!-- replaces the matching ID nodes with the desired output -->
        <xsl:element name="ID">
            <!-- copies all attributes of the current ID node except 'dc' -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() != 'dc']" />
            <!-- sets the attribute to the desired value 'NF' -->                
            <xsl:attribute name="dc">NF</xsl:attribute>
            <!-- applies the rest of the templates -->
            <xsl:apply-templates  />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ID rt="UM" other="attr" dc="NF">
    <foo>bar</foo>
</ID>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="ID">
        <ID>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @rt"/>
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(@dc)">
                <xsl:attribute name="NF" select="@dc"/>

            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

        </ID>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```